# Why is there no $N$ in the time complexity of the QLSP algorithm by Childs et al.?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory, hhl-algorithm

The paper [Quantum linear systems algorithms: a primer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.08227) by Dervovic *et al* has this table on page 3:

[image]

I'm not sure why there's no $N$ in the time complexity of the algorithm by Childs *et al.* i.e. $\mathcal{O}(s\kappa \ \text{polylog}(s\kappa/\epsilon))$. It's a bit hard to believe that the time complexity doesn't depend on the dimensions of the matrix involved. I also checked the [original paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/16M1087072) by Childs *et al* but I couldn't find the time complexity written in this form there. Any ideas?

Comment: In page 3 they define a matrix as sparse when $s=\text{poly}(\log(N))$.

Comment: what are $s$, $\kappa$ and $\epsilon$ here? It might be worth adding it to the post. Anyway, I haven't read the paper but I wouldn't find this too surprising. After all, the sparsity sorts of gives you an "effective dimension" of the matrix. If you increase $N$ with fixed $s$, you are just adding more zeros to the matrix, so it makes sense that you are not really making the problem more difficult to solve.

Comment: @user96233, glS: Yes, upon going through Dervovic's paper that seems like the only plausible explanation so far. Thanks!

Comment: @glS: $\kappa$ is the condition number and $\epsilon$ is the precision term. Smaller $\epsilon$ would imply lesser error. And yeah, I agree on the non-triviality part :P The math in that paper seems almost impenetrable! Would take several days of dedicated reading I guess.